# Powershell get-aduser formatting Write-Host

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script I wish to run and output the results formatted as:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-ADuser j.citizen


DistinguishedName : CN=John Citizen,CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=local
Enabled           : True
GivenName         : John
Name              : John Citizen
ObjectClass       : user
ObjectGUID        : 3ecc1da4-6443-4e77-b594-3061be28a434
SamAccountName    : j.citizen
SID               : S-1-5-21-3281199732-950135425-2894168244-1115
Surname           : Citizen
UserPrincipalName : j.citizen@mydomain.local
```

My Powershell code is:

```
$varAccount = Get-AdUser j.citizen
Write-Host "$varAccount"
```

It outputs:

```
CN=John Citizen,CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=local
```

Comment: What would you like the output to look like?

Comment: Like the output at the top of the post. Two columns.

Comment: `Write-Host ($varAccount |Out-String)`

Answer (score 3):

Then have a look at [Format-List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-list?view=powershell-6)

```
$varAccount = Get-AdUser j.citizen
$varAccount | Format-List -Property *
```

You can also capture this console output in a variable to save it in a text file for instance:

```
$output = $varAccount | Format-List -Property * | Out-String
```

Comment: Can this be used with Write-Host ?

Comment: @Dercni Sure, you can do a `Write-Host $output` anytime. If all you want is the info in a list format on the console window, you don't need `Write-Host`. Capturing in a variable only makes sense if you want to store that somewhere in a text file or use Write-Host to display in another font color for instance.